# Locating instance by ID property in tree structure

Tags: c#, .net, linq, tree

I have a C# class that contains a list of the same class as one of its properties:

```
class MyClass
{
    string id;
    List<MyClass> children;
    //other properties

    public MyClass(string Id, List<MyClass> Children)
    {
        id = Id;
        children = Children;
    }
}
```

In my program, this class is used to create a tree structure (ergo, some items will not have child items). Is there a way to locate an ID within the structure and from there recurse back down the tree to get an array of parent nodes?

I know this is similar to TreeView.FindNode() but I'd like to avoid a derived class if I can.

Comment: Do you have unique Ids?

Comment: Yes, all the IDs are unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do it with recursion:

```
List<MyClass> GetPathToId(string id2find)
{
    if (Id == id2find) return new List<MyClass>(new[] { this });

    if (Children == null) return null;

    List<MyClass> result = Children.Select(e => e.GetPathToId(id2find)).FirstOrDefault(r => r != null);
    if (result != null) result.Insert(0, this);

    return result;
}
```

UPDATE: As doctor correctly pointed out, since I don't know your class, `Children` could be null. I added a null check.

Comment: edited: forgot the "e." in `e.GetPathToId` and creating a StackOverflowException.

Comment: This will throw exception if no id matches the search

Comment: @doctor No it returns null. I tried it with the code you read before my last edit. Edited though for a little better variation.

Comment: It also throws exception when the Id is for a node which does not have any children.

Comment: @doctor Why should it do that? Ok, maybe if `Children` is null, but I supposed OP takes care of that in another part of the class. And for not matchin Id it would have only thrown if you had an extremely large number of levels in the hierarchy. Please prove what you mean. I tried it in Visual Studio and it returns null without throwing!

Comment: @doctor maybe you're talking about my very first version. if so, see my first comment, I forgot to call GetPathToId on the child element and called it on this instead in the linq statement. that of course threw StackOverflowExceptions. But in almost every case, not just for not matching ids.

Comment: You should check for null-ability of `Children`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an extension method which do it using recursion

```
public static class Ex
{
    public static List<MyClass> FindNode(this MyClass t, string id)
    {
        if (t.Id == id)
            return new List<MyClass>() { t };

        if (t.Children == null)
            return null;

        foreach (var child in t.Children)
        {
            var childResult = child.FindNode(id);
            if (childResult != null)
                return new List<MyClass>() { t }.Concat(childResult).ToList();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

It will return the path from root to the instance which contains the specific id.

```
var t1 = new MyClass("1", null);
var t2 = new MyClass("2", null);
var t3 = new MyClass("3", null);
var t4 = new MyClass("4", new List<MyClass>() { t1, t2, t3 });
var t5 = new MyClass("5", null);
var t6 = new MyClass("6", null);
var t7 = new MyClass("7", new List<MyClass>() { t5, t6 });
var t8 = new MyClass("8", new List<MyClass>() { t4, t7 });


var result = t8.FindNode("2");
if (result != null)
    foreach (var myClass in result)
        Console.WriteLine(myClass.Id);
```

result is

> 8
>   4
>   2

Comment: for performance: good way is to create with async method and cancel token :-)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem right, I think one good way to do it is by using two methods. One to find your class recursively by Id, and another to return parent tree of that class in an array, like you want.

```
class MyClass
{
    string id;
    List<MyClass> children;
    MyClass parent;

    public MyClass(string id, List<MyClass> children)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.children = children;

        foreach (var child in children)
        {
            child.parent = this;
        }
    }

    public MyClass Parent { get { return this.parent; } }

    public string Id { get { return this.id; } }

    public List<MyClass> Children { get { return this.children; } }
}

static class Utility
{
    public static MyClass FindMyClassById(IEnumerable<MyClass> myClasses, string id)
    {
        foreach (var myClass in myClasses)
        {
            if (myClass.Id == id)
            {
                return myClass;
            }

            if (myClass.Children != null && myClass.Children.Any())
            {
                return FindMyClassById(myClass.Children, id);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    public static MyClass[] GetParentNodes(MyClass myClass)
    {
        var parents = new List<MyClass>();

        while (myClass != null)
        {
            myClass = myClass.Parent;

            parents.Add(myClass);
        }

        return parents.ToArray();
    }
}
```